# require 'rubygems' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

when I type `irb> require 'rubygems'` it returns false. I have many gems in my rails app that are obviously working - rake, activerecord, etc. What could be going wrong here? thanks.

Ruby 1.8.6.
Rails 1.2.6

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It throws an exception if it doesn't work, it returns false if it is already loaded.